# Integrate facebook Like button for a specific element of my website

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website where i implement a wall of messages, the idea is to add to each of this wall messages a like button, where clicking on it would immediately post on the user's facebook profile page that he likes THAT SPECIFIC COMMENT.

Is this possible? I just enter this new world of facebook php developers, and as far as I have read [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) it always talks about adding a Like button for a specific URL. I would like to make the like button apply for the specific post within the messages wall.

I am clueless as where to start, if by the way any one could recommend a detailed tutorial on how to integrate a website to facebook in its different ways, i would really appreciate it.

**EDIT:** 
Looking into @Kaan Soral suggestion of using open graph, I think it is important to add that I dont want each wall post that the user likes to appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of his profile... This wouldn't make sense because he would rapidly have loads of likes of separate wall posts.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible, read this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

You have to create a URL for every item that will be liked and on that URL there should be META tags for descriptions, image etc

Comment: thank you! I have been looking into it, have a couple of doubts that maybe you can answer. I followed the example provided in the link you posted for the "the rock" movie example. However, then the like button is added like this `<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/" width="450" height="80"/>`, where is the like button actually associated to that determined metatag?